# "vcpkg integrate install" doesn't work for VS2017 with toolset v140

Tags: visual-studio-2017, integration, vcpkg

I have both VS2015 and VS2017. I created an empty project and added an include line with a package installed with vcpkg. The project that I open is setup with target platform version 8.1 and platform toolset v140. The vcpkg integration doesn't work for this configuration under VS2017 (it cant find the included header) but it works under VS2015. With VS2017 and toolset v141 the integration works. I tried to follow prop imports but I can't track it.

vcpkg creates

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\ImportBefore\Default\vcpkg.system.props"
```

which is imported by

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
```

the actual import path in Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props is

```
    "$(VCTargetsPath)\ImportBefore\Default\*.props"
```

For toolset v141 VCTargetsPath is

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\"
```

For toolset v140 VCTargetsPath is

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\"
```

So I would think that this integration shouldn't work for toolset v141 at all, but for some strange reason it works.

In VS2017, toolset v140 the build log shows:

```
    1>VCTargetsPath                  = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\
    1>VCTargetsPathActual            = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\
    1>VCTargetsPathEffective         = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\
```

What is going on?